# How to fill in BURSTIO::BurstSRI in REDHAWK 2.0

Tags: redhawksdr

I am starting to develop some BurstIO based components with REDHAWK 2.0 and the section on BurstIO is missing from the manual on the website. The older 1.10.2 manual seems to cover much of the topic but I am not sure how to fill in the BURSTIO::BurstSRI structure. It looks like there are a few mandatory fields and several fields not described in either manual. I see a flags field that I am assuming is a bit-field for the additional members to determine if they are filled in.

My question is are there #defines or enumerations somewhere for the flags? 
What are the expected values or ranges of values for these fields and is there a standard list of values for variables like the randomizer string somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The undefined fields are user-defined fields.  There are currently not any open conventions for how they are used (that I am aware of).